# "System error 5 has occurred, access denied" when using NET TIME \\[REMOTE] /SET

Tags: command-line, time

Following on from [this answe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304480/synchronizing-time-between-two-pcs-via-tcp-ip-no-server/4304555#4304555)r to my question, I'm getting access denied errors when trying to set time from one PC to another.

I can't find any references for this on StackOverflow, so I think it's a useful resource to have here.

What are the general troubleshooting steps for this problem? *(And more specifically, in my case with two XP embedded in Workgroup mode)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an excellent resource for debugging workgroup problems [here](http://networking.nitecruzr.net/2005/10/irregularities-in-workgroup-visibility.html), I'm copying some of that page here, but please follow the link to get the full details.

> 1. Check for a personal firewall problem. A misconfigured or
>      malfunctioning personal firewall, on
>      either computer, can block browser
>      access. Do you have antivirus
>      protection? Make sure that your
>      antivirus is not part of a package
>      that contains a personal firewall, and
>      does not contain a component that acts
>      as a firewall.
> 2. Look carefully for a hardware firewall, sitting inside your
>      computer. The nVidia nForce is
>      probably the first, but surely not the
>      last, device of this type.
> 3. Some newer, WiFi routers, have a complete firewall between ALL client
>      computers, connected wired or
>      wireless. Look for an "Isolation Mode"
>      setting, if no computers are visible
>      to each other. Each vendor uses a
>      different name for this feature, so
>      read your user guide carefully, if you
>      suspect that this is a problem.
> 4. Make sure that NetBIOS Over TCP is consistently set, in TCP/IP Properties
>      for each computer in your network.
> 5. Does your LAN include any computers running Windows Vista? If so, be aware
>      of the additional issues involved in
>      Windows Vista and Windows Networking.
> 6. Do you have a share setup on each computer? With Windows XP / Vista,
>      only computers with non-administrative
>      shares (not ending in "$") will be
>      visible in My Network Places (aka
>      Network Neighborhood).
> 7. Make sure that all computers are in the same workgroup, if you expect to
>      see them in the root of Network
>      Neighborhood (My Network Places).
> 8. Check for several well known and lesser known registry settings, which
>      will affect visibility of, and access
>      to, your server.
> 9. Look at the content of the error message. Do you see either "error = 5"
>      (aka "access denied"), or "error = 53"
>      (aka "name not found")? Read the
>      appropriate article, and follow the
>      links.
> 10. Look again at the complete and exact text in any observed error
>       messages. Some very obscure errors
>       have very simple resolutions.
> 11. Run, and examine output from, "browstat status", "ipconfig /all",
>       and "net config server" and "net
>       config workstation", for each
>       computer.
> 12. Post output from the above step for expert interpretation and advice.
>       Include relevant background details in
>       your post. When including diagnostic
>       logs, such as "browstat status",
>       "ipconfig /all", or background
>       details, format them properly when you
>       post them.

Comment: There is another great tutorial on the same blog [Solving network problems](http://networking.nitecruzr.net/2005/08/solving-network-problems-tutorial.html)